# Call an Item from a Collection of Items

Tags: excel, vba, class, collections

I have a class "Currency" and a class "Currencies" which is a collection of instances of "Currency" class objects. I think this resembles Excel's `Worksheet` class which is a member of the `Sheets` collection. I can address any member by index or "Key", like `Sheets(1)` or `Sheets("Sheet1").

Here is code from my "Currencies" class module. It's abbreviated for use here and may not run, which is not the issue.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ' Class "Currencies"
    
    Dim R       As Long
    
    Set AllCcys = New Collection
    Arr = .Range("Currencies").Value
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Set Ccy = Me.Add(Arr(R, 1))
    Next R
End Sub

Public Function Add(ByVal Key As String) As cCcy

    Dim Fun     As cCcy

    Set Fun = New cCcy
    AllCcys.Add Fun, Key
    Fun.Key = Key
    Set Add = Fun
End Function

Public Property Get Item(Key As Variant) As cCcy
    Set Item = AllCcys(Key)
End Property
```

With my setup I can access any of the "Currency" objects with syntax like `Currencies.Item("USD").Rate` or `Currencies.Item(1).Rate` which I consider convoluted. I would like to use `Currencies("USD").Rate` analog to what I do when accessing Excel's `Sheets` collection.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx) is what you want - Basically export your `Currencies` class, open in Notepad and add `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0` into your `Item` property.

Comment: @Raymond Wu Yes! This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. Please post it as an "Answer" so that I can select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx, you can specify any procedure in a custom class to be the default member by the steps below:

1. Export `Currencies` class module
2. Open the exported module in Notepad
3. Add `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0` in your `Item` property like this:

```
Public Property Get Item(Key As Variant) As cCcy
    Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0    
    Set Item = AllCcys(Key)
End Property
```

4. Save and Import back into your file.

Note: You can only have 1 procedure be the default member and you will not see the line `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0` in the VBE.